# Edição a revelia

Tags: debate, edições-sugeridas

Quem responde a uma pergunta não deveria ter a opção de não concordar com uma edição sugerida?

A única opção de quem teve sua resposta editada de uma maneira com a qual não concorda é excluir esta resposta?

Comment: Minha resposta abaixo mostra as opções que você tem nessas situações. Porém, se você discorda de uma edição específica, seria interessante incluir aqui na sua pergunta um link para ela, de maneira que possamos opinar sobre sua validade.

Comment: Como não encontrei a opção de reverter a edição feita eu optei por excluir minha resposta. Ela já não está mais em discussão.

Comment: Bom, se você quiser ainda pode desfazer a exclusão. Se achar que vale a pena.

Comment: Eu dei uma olhada na resposta, e na edição, e acho que valeria a pena discutir o que te faz discordar da edição. Concordo com o @bfavaretto sobre desfazer a remoção.

Comment: A única edição que achei em suas respostas que pode ter gerado sua discordância é [esta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/6869/revisions). Confere?

Comment: esses dias também foi editada uma resposta minha, por uma pessoa. que acabou fazendo perder o resultado obtido..e hoje para minha surpresa vi que ele copiou a minha resposta para responder outra pergunta semelhante(sem devido crédito)...essas coisas que me fez perder o  interesse pelo wikipedia... e com certeza irá estragar o SO

Answer (score 5):

Se você não concorda com uma edição, é possível revertê-la. Toda postagem (pergunta ou resposta) editada possui um link para o histórico de edição. Esse link está na palavra "editada", na área que indica quem fez a última edição, e quando. Clicando nele, você verá o histórico de revisões dá postagem. Cada revisão tem um link de reverter. Localize a revisão para a qual quer reverter, e clique no link correspondente.

No caso de edições sugeridas, isso pode nem ser necessário. Se você for o autor da postagem e rejeitar a edição enquanto ela estiver pendente, o seu voto basta para que ela não entre em vigor.